# asp.net DropDownList c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to know how to display data from a dropdown list. For example:

DropDownList

**Select Images**
car
boat
fishing

The first thing the user see is the select images dropdown.  The user will see some random picture that displays from the select image dropdown.

If the user presses the car picture in the list, and then new picture will show and so on.

Each picture will show up in the html table something like the picture that I have drawn (below). Say each list has three pictures, then each of the three will be displayed in the table (as seen below).

[image: sample screenshot]

Here is the code I have written so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;


namespace Prototype
{
    public partial class HomePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                FillddlPictuer();
            }
        }

        public void FillddlPictuer()
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pictuer", conn);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader readeer = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
                    newItem.Text = "Select Image";
                    newItem.Value = "0";
                    ddlMovie.Items.Add(newItem);

                    while (readeer.Read())
                    {
                        newItem = new ListItem();
                        newItem.Text = readeer["name"].ToString();
                        newItem.Value = readeer["id"].ToString();
                        ddlMovie.Items.Add(newItem);
                    }
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                }

                catch
                { 
                    //Handel any error
                    conn.Close();
                }



            } //Close the first using  
        }
    }
}
```

HomePage code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Prototype.HomePage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMainSection" runat="server">
    <div id="ImageGalleryBorder"></div>
    <div id="ChampionBorder"></div>
    <div id="OtherStuffBorder">  
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMainAside" runat="server">
    <h1>New videos</h1>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMovie" runat="server"
        CssClass="DropDownListAside">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to also include you markup.

Comment: html code for website ? or just a picuter?

Comment: The HTML code that goes with your C# code above. Probably "HomePage.aspx".  (also, note that I've corrected your spelling of "picture" in the question.  You're swapping the "r" and the "e" at the end).

Comment: Okey thanks did not see it, I have add the code for the homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change the Picture table in SQL to include a **path** column, this will be used to store the path to the image on the server:
2. Rename Pictuer table to **Picture**

[image]

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMovie" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MovieChanged" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pictures" runat="server" />
        <span id="error" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetPictures();
        AddPicture(ddlMovie.SelectedItem.Value);
        ReDisplayPictures();
    }
}

private void ReDisplayPictures()
{
    List<string> imagePaths = ViewState["Images"] as List<string>;
    if (imagePaths != null)
    {
        foreach (string path in imagePaths)
        {
            var image = new Image{Width = 100,Height = 100,ImageUrl = path};
            pictures.Controls.Add(image);
        }
    }
}

private void AddPicture(string imageUrl)
{
    List<string> imagePaths = ViewState["Images"] as List<string>;
    if (imagePaths == null)
        imagePaths = new List<string>();

    imagePaths.Add(imageUrl);
    ViewState["Images"] = imagePaths;
}

protected void MovieChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddPicture(ddlMovie.SelectedItem.Value);
    ReDisplayPictures();
}

private void GetPictures()
{
    try
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Picture", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string name = reader["name"].ToString();
                    string path = reader["path"].ToString();
                    var item = new ListItem { Text = name, Value = path };
                    ddlMovie.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        error.InnerHtml = String.Format("An error occured, description - {0}",
            eX.Message);
    }
}
```

}

I've created a sample project for you, you can download it [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iPiW5jXDdPdTlTVTFCU3YzSGc/edit?usp=sharing) from Google drive (Just click File->Download)

Comment: I will check the code and then come back. Thanks so much for your reply.

Comment: Ok,good luck with your project and please mark as answered if it helps you

Comment: I got an error 1; The name 'pictuer' does not exist in the current context and the same thing is ddlmovie and error

Comment: copy the code exactly as it is in my answer.if you're having problems download the sample code provided in the answer

Comment: Nothing happens when I press the text here I only get to a empty page. I have copy the code exactly and I got the same errors

Comment: It works now but I cant see the image content it just a empty picture on the screen

Comment: It work now I forgot about the jpg format thanks for the help.

Comment: I try to figuer out how no image is show when the the first iteam are selected. I mean the Select image. And every time I changed back to Select image all image from the other iteam are still there. I have try to figuer it out but.

Comment: It's quite easy all you have to do is call AddPicture and ReDisplayPictures on the FIRST page load and remove the check which prevents duplicate image paths from being added to view state. I've edited my answer with these changes, hope it helps you